# Problemas com "active" ReactJS

Tags: react, react-hooks, styled-components

Estou tentando criar um estado para setar um ícone como `active` mudando sua cor, porém estou falhando miseravelmente por ter pouco conhecimento.

Criei um estado com o `useState` e coloquei o valor true por padrão para poder testar se iria funcionar.

No meu ícone, passei `active={active}` e nos meus estilos, eu peguei ele como:

**styled-components**:

```
svg{
   color: ${props => props.active ? 'cornumero1' : 'cornumero2'};
}
```

---

**index.js**:

```
<li>
 <Icon.GoGraph size={20} active={active} />
 <p>Gestão de cobrança</p>
</li>
```

Eu estou errando em alguma coisa ou esquecendo algo, porque o ícone vem diretamente no `else`, ou seja, como `false`.

Como resolver?

Comment: Olhando pelo que você postou parece estar tudo certo. Tem que ver se essa propriedade active está realmente dentro desse componente onde tem o svg, saca?

Comment: @CarlosQuerioz  Entendi, realmente não deve ter pois é o pacote "react-icons"... mas então, como eu faria para criar isso ? Pois estou usando cerca de uns 20 icones na pagina.

Comment: Acho que uma das possibilidades é você extender o icone no Styled-Component, tipo `const StyledIcon = styled(Icon)` e passar o atributo igual fala na documentação. `const StyledIcon = styled(Icon).attrs(props => ({color: props.active ? cor1 : cor2})`

Comment: Carlos Muito obrigado pela atenção cara, vou ver se consigo do seu jeito depois, eu consegui resolver da seguinte forma, Passei a props no item, vc tinha razão, o icone ali nao aceitava essa props, dai passei na tag pai... e ja extendi essa mesma logica para atribuir valores ao BEFORE e AFTER, interessante que funciona o content com variaveis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meu problema era estar passando a `props` no Icon, o correto é na `<li>` como um novo componente e agradeço a todos que me ajudaram e em especial ao Carlos Queiroz  que me orientou.

Final:

**index.js**:

```
<Item active={active}>
  <Icon.GoGraph size={20} />
  <p>Gestão de cobrança</p>
</Item>
```

---

**styles**:

```
export const Item = styled.li`
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  svg {
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    color: ${props => (props.active ? '#47B248' : '#939393')};
  }`
```